# How to calculate the work done by squeezing an air balloon (or pushing a piston)?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, energy-conservation, work, ideal-gas

Boyle's Law states that the product of the pressure and volume of an ideal gas under constant temperature is constant. That is:
$P_i  V_i = P_f  V_f$.

But what happens when temperature is not constant? I suppose squeezing affects the temperature of the gas (neglecting the heat transfer between the balloon and hand)? How do we calculate the work done in this case?

Note that if we assume the temperature constant, then the work must be zero as $P . V$ yields energy and it is always constant, which does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) "But what happens when temperature is not constant? I suppose squeezing affects the temperature of the gas (neglecting the heat transfer between the balloon and hand)? How do we calculate the work done in this case?"

This is the so-called *adiabatic* change: no heat transfer to or from surroundings. The work that you do in squeezing the balloon to make its volume decrease goes to raising the internal energy of the gas inside it, and so raising its temperature. For *n* moles of an ideal monatomic gas the work done is given by   $$W=\tfrac32nR\Delta T$$ in which $\Delta T$ is the temperature rise of the gas. This can be related to what happens to the pressure and volume of the gas using the ideal gas equation and a little gentle calculus. It is standard textbook stuff.

(b) "Note that if we assume the temperature constant, then the work must be zero as P x V yields energy" No. $pV$ has the *dimensions* of energy and the product $pV$ does feature in various thermodynamic energy formulae, but your conclusion about work simply doesn't follow.

Comment: Thank you Philip. For a) Would you expand your answer by providing the standard textbook stuff? Because PV=nRT does not seem to yield the temperature rise to me. For b) assuming constant temperature means we remove heat from the system while squeezing the balloon which might keep the work at 0. Don't you think?

Comment: (a) "Would you expand your answer by providing the standard textbook stuff?" I don't mean to be rude, but don't you have a textbook? And have you checked websites? (b) If you're squeezing the balloon and making its volume smaller, then you are doing work on the gas. The work can't be zero. In an isothermal compression of an ideal gas, heat must leave the gas at the same rate that work is being done on it. This follows from the First Law of Thermodynamics and the fact that for an ideal gas the internal energy depends only on temperature.

Comment: Hey Philip. I already checked the pages and formulas about ideal gases before writing here. The thing is non-constant-tempereture case is not an easy "standard textbook stuff". Here is the page from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law. Can you point me two formulas that will solve a situation with two variables (pressure and temperature) having unknown final values. That is, we know all the initial values and the final volume but we don't we know the final pressure and the final temperature. According to you, what are the formulas yielding the equilibrium point?

Comment: Your original question asked about reversible adiabatic changes (no heat transfer). Are these still what you're interested in?

Comment: To Philip. I take your last comment as a hint. So it looks like I need to use the Isentropic process formulas where entropy is constant. Since we know $V2/V1$ ratio the related formulas seem to be: $P2 = P1(V2/V1)^{-γ}$ and $T2 = T1(V2/V1)^{(1-γ)}$, where γ is typically 1.4 for diatomic gases and 1.6 for mono atomic gases. What are your comments?

Comment: That's right. $\gamma$ is 7/5 for diatomic gases and 5/3 for monatomic gases. The formula to remember is $pV^\gamma = \text{constant}$ for an adiabatic change. The relations between $p$ and $T$ and between $V$ and $T$ for an adiabatic change can be found from $pV^\gamma = \text{constant}$ using $pV=nRT$ to eliminate the unwanted variable.

Comment: To Philip. Thanks a lot. However $pV^γ=C$ formula seems to be valid for polytropic processes which, according to Wikipedia, can describe multiple expansion and compression processes which include heat transfer. Since the case I asked does not include heat transfer, it looks like I need to stick with Isentropic process formulas.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Philip. You helped a lot.

Comment: Thank you. But there was a mistake in my last comment. It should have read: you asked originally about the work done in such a process, and I gave you a formula for the work done on the gas in my original answer. Note that you can use the ideal gas equation to express the work done by a monatomic gas) as $- \frac32 (_2_2-p_1V_1)$.

Comment: To Philip. Yes, this part was not so clear to me but I did not want to take your time more than I already did :) Thanks again for all the effort. Take care.

Comment: Hi Philip. I revisited the question to accept it, but the connection to the final temperature is not clear. Note that we don't know the final temperature in this question. The equations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law#Applications_to_thermodynamic_processes) fill that gap for different constants like pressure, volume, entropy etc. Would you add the relevant equations (e.g. constant entropy) in your answer just to make it more clear for everyone?